# What is the significance of a mostly blank user card?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-interface, users, user-card

What does it mean when the "user-details" block of a "user card" of an answer has a name but no link, no reputation, and no badges?

[image]

For example: on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104/smarter-vim-recovery/623663#623663) by "Peter" on Mar 8 '09 at 14:26

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general it means that account either:

1. was deleted
2. does not exist on the current site but did exist on the site the question originated on when it was migrated (in the case of migrated questions)

   - note:  the account may have been deleted on the source site since then as well
   - if the user from the original site of the migrated question then registers on the target site, it will update their user card with their new profile details for the target site

Since this was not a migrated question, only #1 applies here, so we can conclude the account has been deleted since the answer was posted.

Comment: And someone who can confirm this can edit it in, but I think that if a user on a migrated question then registers/associates on the target site, it will associate their response on that question as well and their user card will have their new details

Comment: that's exactly right.

Answer (score 5):

In this case it is a deleted account.

It can also happen when a question is migrated — any posters that do not have accounts on the new site will appear in the same format.

Answer (score -1):

Yours is nothing! This is a real blank one:

[image]