# User information is not showing

Tags: support, bug, design, community-wiki

I have seen a question where user information isn't mentioned in the question:

> [image]

*[What's the primary use of Windows Event Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442115/whats-the-primary-use-of-windows-event-viewer#comment104048211_2442115)*

When I checked if the bug reported earlier, I found: *[What is the significance of a mostly blank user card?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89301/what-is-the-significance-of-a-mostly-blank-user-card)*

Two reasons were mentioned there:

1. The account was deleted
2. It does not exist on the current site, but it did exist on the site the question originated on when it was migrated (in the case of migrated questions).

Here, in this case, I have checked, both the user account are existing and active (if you check in detail specific user information):

> [image]

Also, the question has not been migrated from anywhere.

Is it a design problem?

Comment: The post is community wiki, which means it no longer "belongs" to one user, hence the different usercard. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247110/who-actually-owns-community-wiki-posts